# How to parse raw activity data received from Mi Band

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement simple app which is showing activity data recevied from Xiaomi Mi Band. At the moment i can track steps in realtime, measure heartrate and initiate vibration. Mi Band provides raw data that show activity statistic (sleep activity, walking periods). I know how to get that data, moreover, I know the structure of that data: `timestamp`, `provider`, `intensity`, `steps`, `type`. Mi Band generate this objects every minute (in theory), but it is hard to split the array of this objects to activity periods e. g. 15:34 - 16:41 - 6412 steps. Analyse the raw data shows very strange picture: there are many objects with steps when the tracker just lay on the table. **BUT**! Native application "Mi Fit" accurately measures the activity periods of day...
I know that this is very specific topic, but I hope that somebody will help me)

My repo:
https://github.com/AlexanderHryk/MiFood

Comment: How do you get that raw data? Do you have an sdk?

Comment: Check the repo. There is a code that implements that feature.